# How can a Google Sheet Commenter receive all Notifications from all user's comments?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, comments

I have a Google sheet that I share with many collaborators who have "Commenter" privileges.
They are notified only if a comment is mentioned with the "@their email" symbol unless they go and change that from "Notification Settings" to receive "All comments".
Is there a way to create a script that will send to all commenters all comments written inside the Google sheet?

In this case, what values do you want to send as an email?
[image]
[image]

If you write a comment in Google Sheets the owner of the Excel file is receiving that information that shows in my picture inside the post.
I want the same thing with the script.

That is:

The name of the commenter,

The file name,

The cell title,

The comment, and

the option to reply or to open the Google sheet in the cell with the comment.
fileId: string - The ID of the file.
commented: string - The ID of the comment.

Comment: About `Is there a way to create a script that will send to all commenters all comments written inside the Google sheet?`, in this case, when a script is run, do you want to retrieve all comments and put all comments to all shared users? Or, when a comment is posted, do you want to put a new comment to all shared users?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, nice to hear from you!
"when a script is run, do you want to retrieve all comments and put all comments to all shared users?" 
Yes, to all users that have comment or viewer privileges.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From ` "when a script is run, do you want to retrieve all comments and put all comments to all shared users?" Yes, to all users that have comment or viewer privileges.`, I understood that you wanted to send all comments to all shared users as an email. In this case, what values do you want to send as an email? There are several properties in [Method: comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/comments/list) for retrieving the comments from Spreadsheet.

Comment: About `Please check my other question if you can since you are the only one who knows 100% the Google sheet script that I am using from my previous post which is yours. stackoverflow.com/q/78223178/22804395`, when I saw your other question, it seems that 2 answers have already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answers. I would like to believe that the owners of those answers will resolve your question.

Comment: I added two captures of what I am receiving today.
I believe it should be:

fileId: string
The ID of the file. 

commented: string 
The ID of the comment.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I have edited post with an answer to your comment.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly understand your expected result, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: All shared users receive email notifications when a comment is written. Is that more clear?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `All shared users receive email notifications when a comment is written. Is that more clear?`, I'm worried that unfortunately, directly notifying all shared users with email upon a comment might not be possible. I'm currently exploring alternative approaches. I apologize that I can't provide a solution immediately. I appreciate your patience and will keep studying to improve my capabilities.